# Calculate minutes in every month (php)

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to calculate the minutes in any month for any year. For example, I want to show for 2013, 2014, and 2015 (and any other year) that January has 4460 minutes, September has 43200 minutes, etc. I could probably hard-code that, but the issue is obviously February. If it is a leap year, it has 41760 minutes, if it isn't it has 40320 minutes. I guess I'm not even sure what the best way to approach this is. Maybe something with date("t") and mktime? Write something that only changes Feb. if it is a leap year? Any guidance is appreciated.

Edit: as requested, what I have tried (and failed with)...

```
$totaldays = date("t", mktime($month));

if $totaldays=31
    $totmin=44640
elseif $totaldays=30
    $totmin=43200
elseif $totaldays=29
    $totmin=41760
else $totaldays=28
    $totmin=40320
```

Comment: Google for a snippet on how to get the amount of days from any given month. The rest should be trivial, except you are dealing with leap seconds, etc.

Comment: What's the problem? You have already found `date('t')` so it's a simple multiplication.

Comment: Dealing with daylight savings transitions will also be an issue

Comment: `date('t') * 24 * 60`?

Comment: For the sake of keeping this question open, please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leap seconds aside, I think this should work:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2014-02-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1Y');
$period = new DatePeriod($datetime, $interval, 5);
foreach($period as $month) {
    echo $month->format('Y-m-d') . ': ' . $month->format('t') * 1440 . "<br>\n";
}
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MJJfgn)

Comment: Deals just with February, which works for my purposes. I can hardcode the others in (which for my purposes, remain static at 30 or 31 days)

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/cal-days-in-month

```
int cal_days_in_month ( int $calendar , int $month , int $year )
```

Fill in the params, and multiply the integer by `(24 * 60)`

Example:

```
$minutes = (24 * 60) * cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m'), date('Y'));
```

Comment: To get function `cal_days_in_month()` to work, you have to compile PHP with `--enable-calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how you're doing your logic - with hard-coded values, or something else, but to check if it's a leap year, do;

```
        if( date("L", time() ) { //It's a leap year!
              $intTotalMinute += 41760;
        } else {
              $intTotalMinute += 40320;   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get number of **minutes for selected year**:

```php
function getYearMinutes($year) {
    $days = 365 + date('L', strtotime("first day of January $year"));
    return $days * 24 * 60;
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/98114)</kbd>